# Finite intersection of nonempty sets is not empty (Poincaré-Miranda theorem)

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, differential-topology, roots

I am trying to understand a proof of the [Poincaré-Miranda theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Miranda_theorem) given in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975081?origin=crossref&seq=1).
So, the theorem states that if we have a continuous map $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n) : I^n \rightarrow {\rm I\!R}^n$ where $I^n$ is a $n$-dimensional cube $[-1, 1]^n$ that satisfies the following condition:
$$
f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, -1, x_{i+1}, \ldots, n) \leq 0 \\
f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, 1, x_{i+1}, \ldots, n) \geq 0
$$
for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, there exists a point $c \in I^n$ such that $f(c) = 0$.

To prove the theorem authors defined sets
$$
H_i^- := f_i^{-1}(- \infty , 0] \\
H_i^+ := f_i^{-1}[0, \infty)
$$
Then they say that "using a compactness argument we infer that the intersection
$$
H := \bigcap \{ H_i^- \cap H_i^+ : i=1, \ldots, n\}
$$
is not empty."

I see that each $H_i^-$ and $H_i^+$ is not empty as it follows from the propositions, but why are $H_i^- \cap H_i^+$ nonempty and why is $H$ not empty?

Additionally, if $H$ is indeed not empty, it is obvious that for every $x \in H$ it follows $f(x) = 0$, so we found the zero. Why does not the proof just end here?

Thanks to anyone who could help me understand.

Comment: Interesting. This is definitely not how I would have proved the result to myself. I probably would have used contradiction. I'll think about this for a minute and get back to if I have a good answer.

Comment: I agree, this is definitely not intuitive proof. Thanks, I will be thankful for any help :)

Comment: So to answer your first question $H_i^{-} \cap H_i^{+}$ is non-empty because the sets in the intersection are a preimage of the same function on two sets that share a common point (specifically, $y=0$).

Answer (score 2):

Their proof is laid out backwards and is indeed confusing. Their general proof is that they can show their are an odd (and so at least 1) simplices of each given diameter that intersect both $H_i^{-}$ and $H_i^{+}$ for all $i$. They then effectively wave their hands and say that's sufficient to prove that $H$ is nonempty by an unstated compactness argument before going back and proving the existence of such simplices.

Here's one way of showing the compactness part. Let $S_k$ be a simplex with diameter $1/k$ which intersect $H_i^-$ and $H_i^+$ for all $i$. Then for all $k$ there are exist $a_k$  in $S_k \cap H_i^-$ and $b_k$ in $S_k \cap H_i^+$ for all i. Then, by compactness, there is some convergent subsequence of the $a_k$. Let that subsequence be $a_{k_i}$ and let its limit be $a$. Note that $a\in H_i^-$ for all $i$ since they are closed. Since the diameter of $S_{k_i}$ is $1/k_i$, the distance $d(a_{k_i},b_{k_i})<1/k_i$ goes to 0, so $a=\lim a_{k_i}=\lim b_{k_i}$. Since $b_{k_i}$ are in the closed set $H_i^+$ for all $i$, the limit $a$ is in $H_i^+$ for all $i$, so $a\in H$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped a lot. But I have some questions. If $k = 1$ it seems intuitive that $S_k$ intersects $H_i^-$ and $H_i^+$, but how do we see that for arbitrary $k$? And generally, a diameter of a simplex is the maximum distance between its points. You define it as distance between neighbouring points if I am correct? As the definition of a simplex in this article is that a simplex is an ordered set of points, $S = [z_1, \ldots, z_n]$ such that $z_i = z_{i-1} + e_i$ where $e_i$ is one of the base vectors.

Comment: Look at the proof in the link. They do an induction argument that the number of such simplices which intersect all the H's for each fixed k is odd. Odd numbers are nonzero.
Yes, the diameter is the max distance. $a_k$ and $b_k$ are both in the same simplex, so they're distance from each other is less than the diameter. The diameter goes to 0, so they're distance from each other goes to 0. I may be off by a small constant depending on the exact definition of $S_k$.